# Cannot access a disposed object in ASP.Net Core Trigger

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, triggers

I am new in ASP.Net Core and I am trying to use trigger in my ASP.Net Core project.
In my project when I want to insert a "BILL" then below error showing :

**Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application.**

Below is my trigger code :

```
        Triggers<Bill>.Inserted += async e =>
        {
           await PaymentStatusChangeNotifierAsync(e); //here Error shows
        };

        private static async Task<int> 
        PaymentStatusChangeNotifierAsync(IEntry<Bill, 
        Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext> e){

        }
```

I am trying for 1 day but unable to solve this problem. How can I solve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `DbContext` has request scope lifetime, meaning that it is created on each request and disposed after request is done. In that line where error occurs, dbcontext object is captured but when that code is executed, request is already served, db context is disposed and you get that error.

Comment: @tchelidze: `DbContext` has no inherent scope. It's typically created "scoped" or in request-scope, but that is not a given.

Comment: It appears you're using the unofficial EntityFrameworkCore.Triggers package. Frankly, looking over the API, there's an uncomfortable amount of "magic" there for me. If I had to guess, I'd say the problem is actually your async lambda. More likely than not, the triggers are run sync, and the synchronization context is being lost (along with your `DbContext`). Interestingly, there's no examples provided of doing async operations in a trigger. You might want to file an issue on the Github project for better assistance.